# Moving central administration from not existing host site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, central-administration

I have SharePoint 2010 environment with multiple servers and the server on which central administration was configured were removed. So now when I try to access central administration through "Start" it still leads to old host, even though it seems our administrators configured it on the new server, because when I try to access it directly through URL it leads to central administration without a problem. I would love to fix this issue and move central administration host to other server.

If my description is lacking or even incorrect, so if there is questions ask and I will update the description.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue and how to fix it. Needed to access CA directly and reconfigure alternate mappings for central administration host

Answer (score 0):

Another way of changing the Central Admin URL is to run the SharePoint products configuration wizard.

From there you can choose to remove the CA web application.

If you run the products configuration wizard again after that, you can choose to redeploy the CA web application.

Comment: Like  I wrote (maybe not clearly) our administrators most likely had already done that, it was first thing I tried to do myself, the issue was with the alternate mappings inside of CA itself, still thanks for help